# nginx is serving vtt as txt

Tags: nginx, server, nginx-config

we have a very simple nginx server that just serves .m3u8 and .vtt files but the problem is when we fetch .vtt file it comes as "example.vtt.txt" I added .vtt in mime.types but it didn't change anything.

thanks for your help!